# MSBuild Multi-Proc

Tags: team-foundation-server

Alguem ai já utilizou o MSBuild Multi-Proc?
Estou tentando utilizar aqui, mas eu acabo recebendo o seguinte erro:

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>    (3390): Unable to copy file "obj\Release\dbShared.dll"
>    to "f:\Build\10\TI\folder\src\Componentes\bin\dbShared.dll". Access to the path 'f:\Build\10\TI\folder\src\Componentes\bin\dbShared.dll'
>    is denied.

Tentei vários parâmetros do MSBuild mas não obtive sucesso.

Se alguem puder me ajudar com isso, ficarei grato.

PS: estou usando o TFS 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O processo que está a correr o MSBuild tem permissões para escrever nesse caminho? Experimente correr como administrador e veja o resultado.

Outra razão pode ser o facto de estarem dois projectos a tentar escrever o mesmo ficheiro para o mesmo caminho. Experimente correr o MSBuild com /p:BuildInParallel=false e veja se o erro persiste.

Nota:
Se forem cópias duplicadas durante o build, [este](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/buckh/a-tool-to-find-duplicate-copies-in-a-build/) é um bom guia para encontrar e resolver a situação.

Comment: Eu concedi a permissão ao usuário que executa o Build Controller no diretório, ejá testei esse parametro, e sim o mesmo erro ocorre. Vou dar uma olhada no guia que informou para ver se consigo resolver o problema.